# Set To field in Outlook mail to Excel cell value

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I borrowed code from Ron De Bruin to email a selection from a worksheet to an email recipient.

I want to specify the address it sends to, from a cell in the worksheet, which is chosen by the data input (which is a vlookup from another sheet).

How do I substitute the `to = "email address"` to a value from a cell in the active sheet?

```
Sub Mail_Selection()
    ' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Recip As String

    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        msgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected.  " & _
               "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Or _
       Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Or _
       Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        msgBox "An Error occurred :" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "You selected more than one sheet." & vbNewLine & _
               "You selected only one cell." & vbNewLine & _
               "You selected more than one area." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Selection of " & wb.Name & " " _
                 & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        ' You are using Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, or Excel 2010.
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        ' You are using Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, or Excel 2010.
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
                FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "email.address.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following statement.
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
            ' display the e-mail message.
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been given an answer to this now by adding the following;

```
'Set the EmailAddressVariable to the value in the approvals worksheet in cell A1
Dim EmailAddressVariable As String
EmailAddressVariable = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
'next point the .to statement to the variable
.to = EmailAddressVariable
```

The only catch was I had to place the EmailAddressVariable = statement above the following statement;

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
```

Now it works a charm - Thanks to BellyGas on Excel Forum!

I hope this is of use to others.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure what you have tried, this is how I would go about it.

```
Dim emailRange as Range
Set emailRange = 'Insert your range here, not sure what "data inputer" is
OutMail.to = emailRange.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line of code:

```
.to = "email.address.com"
```

to the following one:

```
.To = ActiveCell.Value
```